# When creating a simple calculator in C using the switch statement, why do we have to specify the operator before entering the numbers?

Tags: c, switch-statement

Case 1:

```
printf("Enter the operation you want to carry out (+, -, /, *): ");
scanf("%c", &operator);

printf("Enter two numbers: ");
scanf("%lf %lf", &num_1, &num_2);
```

In this case, the program was executed smoothly.

Case 2:

```
printf("Enter two numbers: ");
scanf("%lf %lf", &num_1, &num_2);

printf("Enter the operation you want to carry out (+, -, /, *): ");
scanf("%c", &operator);
```

In this case, after I entered the numbers, it directly executed the rest of the program and the default error message was printed.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: There's no switch statement in your question, the problem is just with `scanf()`.

Comment: Try printing the numeric value of `operator` and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Because, per [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html):

> Most conversions discard initial white space characters (the exceptions are noted below)

one of those exceptions being `%c`.

The newline you input when you hit "enter" in your terminal is a character. When the program is waiting for a `%lf` it just discards that, but for `%c` it is used as the accepted input.

Ideally, you wouldn't need to hit "enter" at all, but many (most?) terminals are line-buffered by default, so nothing gets sent to your program until you do. For a more flexible UI, use something like *curses* or a proper graphical interface.